# Setting the original dropdown text back in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a different value from a dropdown and checking a logic based on the newly selected text from the dropdown list and comparing the text entered in a textbox. If the selected dropdown text and the text box value fails the logic, i want to revert back to the original text that was previously showing in the dropdown box.

For ex: In my dropdown box, i have values as "Valid", "Invalid", "PCR IN", "PCR OUT" and the dropdown already displays "Valid".  If the user changes the value from "Valid" to "PCR IN" and the 2nd textbox value if changed to a negative number, i am throwing an error via bootbox to the user, saying the textbox value should be in positive.

But i needed to change the original value to "Valid" that was showing in the dropdown before the user changed to "PCR IN".  My code is not functioning as desired. It puts a empty result in the dropdown [attached][image: empty value]

My code below:
My MVC View page for creating the dropdown model:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FundingStatusId, new SelectList(ViewBag.FundingStatusDdl, "FundingStatusId", "FundingStatusName"), "Select Fund Status", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control rtscustomtextboxright", @id = "fundingstatus" })

$(function () {
        var fundingStat = $("#fundingstatus option:selected").text();
       
        $("#fundingstatus").change(function () {
            if ($("#fundingstatus option:selected").text() == 'PCR IN') {
                //  debugger
                if (parseFloat($('#additionalFunds').val(), 10) > 0) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        title: "ERROR - Please fix this",
                        size: "lg",
                        message: "<br><br><br>Additional Funds must be a NEGATIVE $ amount"
                    })
                   // return false;
                    $("#fundingstatus").val(fundingStat);
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're using the .val() method wrong.

```
var fundingStat = $("#fundingstatus option:selected").text();
$("#fundingstatus").val(fundingStat); // you set the val for the option's text and not its value.
```

You don't mention the dropdown's code in your question so I can't write the fix but checkout the following explanation:

if we have the following dropdown:

```
<div class="test">
  <select>
    <option value="a">First Choice</option>
    <option value="b">Second Choice</option>
    <option value="c">Third Choice</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

In order to set the selected option we should use the .val() with the **value** and not the **text()**.

```
$(".text select").val("b"); // will select the "Second Choice"
```

**And not**:

```
$(".text select").val("Second Choice");
```

Comment: @Offir Baruch, i have edited my post to show how i am creating the dropdown list using MVC View...

Comment: So maybe:         var fundingStat2 = $("#fundingstatus option:selected").val(); and in the end:                     $("#fundingstatus").val(fundingStat2); ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ofir Baruch, your method worked for me, much appreciated